# Archived version of unity.ubuntu.com

Tags: unity

is there an archived version of https://unity.ubuntu.com ?

The url doesn't work anymore and archive.org doesn't have a complete mirror https://web.archive.org/web/20170829034442/http://unity.ubuntu.com/

Is there a git repository or some other copy I could download or browse?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

Current site is https://ubuntuunity.org/

For any Ubuntu *flavor* site I'd suggest going to a Ubuntu site such as https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours

For some sites, search engines like *google* can send you to *fan*, *fake* or legitimate sites, where Ubuntu sites will send you to official sites.

Being an official flavor, all source code, [*seeds*](https://ubuntu-archive-team.ubuntu.com/seeds/ubuntu-unity.lunar/desktop) etc are available using normal Ubuntu sites (*for 23.04 & later where Ubuntu Unity is an official flavor*)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. ubuntuunity.org is the "new" unity. I am looking for the old website and its content.

Comment: Ubuntu Unity are still using Unity 7 (ie. the same code, but working on a newer GTK base given the older one is *deprecated* and isn't maintained/supported). Only the UBports are using Unity 8 (Qt5 based)

Comment: Hi @guiverc Do you think it's possible the change the current unity to make it look like the unity in Ubuntu 16.04 ? (I am willing to spend lots of time learning)

Comment: I'm no expert on Unity (DE) sorry, but look like for the most part I'd say yes. Some behavior has changed, as many *patches* carried by Ubuntu Desktop (*when Unity 7 was the default DE*) are no longer carried (*unhelpful with GNOME default*) so it's not identical, but its 95%+ the same. Theming can of course be changed; the team provide support *directly* via telegram & even on a discourse.

Comment: Ok, thank you for your time.